# Multiword synonyms and odd token order

Tags: solr, lucene, elasticsearch

Why is the synonymTokenFilter putting the expanded term right after the match of the first token in a multiword synonym? While I'm using elasticsearch, this certainly would apply to any solr/lucene gurus out there as well. I am only applying this during index time, but it is in conjunction with shingles, so the order is extremely important.

I have a synonym:

popcorn popper,popcorn machine

My synonymTokenFilter has expand=true via defaults in elasticsearch.

When I view my tokens, popcorn machine is always inserted between popcorn and popper regardless whether the input term is popcorn popper or popcorn machine.

Example analyzing "*popcorn popper*"

```
 t1:Popcorn t2:popcorn t3:machine t4:popper
```

Example analyzing "*popcorn machine*"

```
  t1:Popcorn t2:popcorn t3:machine t4:popper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lucene token stream [is actually a graph](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/04/lucenes-tokenstreams-are-actually.html). Things like synonyms really cause problems with that graph model and token offsets. Things are however improving in the newer Lucene versions. You just may need to look at (Solr and Lucene) Jiras to find the relevant discussions.